# Concise way to run code 0 to N times in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is there a concise way to run some code 0 to N times in Elixir?

My specific use case is for star ratings in an `Eex` template. If the rating is 0, output 0 stars; if 1, output 1 star, etc.

`List.duplicate/2` and `String.duplicate/2` are along the right lines, but don't work well for HTML in an `Eex` template.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
<%= for _i <- List.duplicate(true, star_count) do  %>
  <svg...>svg data here</svg>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: FWIW, Ruby allows `3.times.each` or `3.times.map`. `0.times.each` does nothing, as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for i <- 0..n, i > 0, do: ...
```

Comment: This will never run 0 times. Even if the range is (0..0) it seems to run at least once.

Comment: @skryl did you forget the `i > 0,` filter? `for i <- 0..0, i > 0, do: IO.puts i` never outputs `i`, but without the filter, it does.

Comment: I thought one could also write `for i <- 1..n, do: ...`, but apparently this wouldn't take care of scenarios where `n` <= 0. So this makes sense.

Comment: @xji because Elixir supports reversed ranges and `for i <- 1..0, do: i #⇒ [1, 0]`.